# Кто такой математик - системный программист?

Tags: терминология

Какая сфера деятельности и тд?
Я так понимаю, это написание драйверов и тому подобного?

Comment: Это что, название специальности в дипломе?

Comment: [математик - и кто же он ?][1] )))


  [1]: http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA

Comment: да. выбираю куда поступать.
факультет "прикладная математика и физика", кафедра "вычислительная математика и программирование", специализация "математик, системный программист". Толком никакой информации. Поверхностно узнал, что это связано с написанием драйверов и тому подобных вещей. Но ничего конкретного. Думаю, тут есть люди, которые разбираются в вопросе.

Comment: спасибо) но я больше про системного программиста спрашиваю

Comment: Вообщем вот ахаха (поторопился с вопросом..но все равно будут интересны ответы по теме):
системный программист 
Человек, который специализируется по системному программированию и программному обеспечению нижнего уровня, т. е. операционным системам, компиляторам, системам связи и системам управления базами данных
системное программирование
Работа, выполняемая системными программистами, т. е. создание системного программного обеспечения. Граница между системным программированием и прикладным программированием зависит от обстоятельств.

Comment: в универе никто вас не будеть учит написанию драйверов! 
А то не осталось бы преподов в универе))) 
Верьте мне, а написали - имееться ввиду, что полученными знаниями вы сами можете написать драйвера.
 для того и придеться трудиться, так как драйверы системы 
не просто так копипастом получиться. Главное верьте в себя.
 и поступайте понравившийся вам специальности.

Comment: Знаешь как все будет?
1курс- матан,химия,философия и море естественный предметов и Pascal
2 курс-матан,физика ,куча естественных наук и С++
3 курс- матан,физика,естественные науки Java/C# 
4-5 курс построены практически на саморазвитии.

Comment: Не то что от названия специальности или факультета, от профиля института (ну, не будем брать медицину, гуманитарные и т.п.) род занятий (реальное место работы) не очень-то и зависит.

Вот я, например, по образованию инженер-экономист по управлению в химической промышленности, а все время (курса с третьего) программы писал.

Comment: страна? если страна бывшего СССР - то сфера деятельности полностью зависит от Вас, начиная от *свободная касса* до специалиста в нейробиологии.

Comment: Это, скорее всего, написание программ для микроконтроллеров *(раз системный)*, которые реализуют в алгоритмах некую математическую модель *(раз математик)*.

Answer (score 5):

1. Написание драйверов под устройства, разработка частей операционной системы - это системый программист, еще сюда относят написание разных сервисов или демонов, типа  узкопрофилированных  серверов, модулей к существующим сервисам
2. разработка и реализация алгоритмов (алгоритм расчета систем дифф уравнений, интегральных алгоритмов, алгоритмов шифрования)  - это программист математик
3. есть еще прикладной программист - это разработка прикладных программ, т.е. пользовательских
4. Есть программист БД - человек специализирующийся в систематизации и извлечении данных из БД

как правило надо знать многое или почти всё :(

я не совсем понял, что ты хочешь узнать?

Comment: Вот примерно это. Спасибо

Comment: Только не надо ожидать что этому всему будет кто-то учить.

Comment: Да это понятно

Comment: Кто сказал что под "система" в названии специальности подразумевается обязательно операционная система, а не обобщение в виде любой системы? :)

Comment: традиционно, лет так 25 - 45 назад всех поделили на две категории:
те кто пишут ось и те кто пришут программы под эту ось...
под системным программированием подразумевается разработка частей операционной системы, на практике же системный программист разрабатывает какие-то части, тесно связанные с ОС, например сетевые демоны, работа с внешними устройствами

Comment: @akalend, на практике (у нас) таких *"системопишущих"* очень мало. В основном люди занимаются системным администрированием (установка, настройка) и системной интеграцией (это в основном у продавцов).